# React, patch call submits older data even after state has updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am trying to send the state after it has been updated to the database, but for some reason when the .patch is triggered it sends the state prior to the update.

When I do `console.log()` I can see that the state when saveChangeHandler is called is the previous state, yet the `console.log()` `useSelector` gives me the latest state.

I have tried async await but that gave me the same results, I have put the `saveChangesHandler` inside the `updateNodeHandler` and that was not fruitful either, what am I missing?

The button calls `updateNodeHandler` and `saveChangesHandler` once it has been clicked

```
                        <button
                          type="submit"
                          disabled
                          // style={{ marginLeft: "-6px" }}
                          onClick={() => {
                            updateNodeHandler(elements);
                            saveChangesHandler();
                          }}
                        >
                          Save Changes
                        </button>
```

This is my general code:

```
  const elements = useSelector(state => state.step.NodeElements)

  const updateNodeHandler = () => {
    if (!activeNode) return;
    const element = elements.find((element) => {
      return element.id === activeNode.id
    })
    dispatch(editStep(
          {
            id: activeNode.id,
            text: newtext
          }
    ));
    console.log(elements, "in update nodeshandler")
  };


  const saveChangesHandler = () => {
    const steps = {
      "steps": elements
    }
    console.log(elements)

    getAuthorization()
      .patch(`product/save_data/${ID}/`, steps)
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("err", err);
      });
  };
```

This is the slice:

```
editStep(state: any, action) {
  console.log(action.payload.id);
  return {
    ...state,
    NodeElements: state.NodeElements.map((step) =>
      step.id === action.payload.id
        ? {
            ...action.payload,
          }
        : step
    ),
  };
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that of a stale enclosure. The button's `onClick` handler has a closure over the current `elements` state value when the callback is invoked. `updateNodeHandler(elements);` dispatches an action to update the store, but the component hasn't rerendered yet to pick up the updated `elements` state value when `saveChangesHandler();` is called.

A solution that won't require refactoring any of the handlers and functions would be to import the `store` object and access the current state in the `saveChangesHandler` handler.

Exmaple:

```
import { store } from '../path/to/store';

...

const saveChangesHandler = () => {
  const state = store.getState();
  const elements = state.step.NodeElements;

  const steps = {
    steps: elements,
  };

  console.log(elements);

  getAuthorization()
    .patch(`product/save_data/${ID}/`, steps)
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("err", err);
    });
};

...
```

The more correct fix may be to convert `saveChangesHandler` into an asynchronous action. It could look something like the following:

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const saveChangesHandler = createAsyncThunk(
  'step/saveChangesHandler',
  ({ id }, { getState, rejectWithValue }) => {
  const state = getState();
  const elements = state.step.NodeElements;

  const steps = {
    steps: elements,
  };

  console.log(elements);

  return getAuthorization()
    .patch(`product/save_data/${id}/`, steps)
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("err", err);
      rejectWithValue(err);
    });
};
```

```
const elements = useSelector(state => state.step.NodeElements)

const updateNodeHandler = (elements) => {
  if (!activeNode) return;
  const element = elements.find((element) => {
    return element.id === activeNode.id
  })
  dispatch(editStep({
    id: activeNode.id,
    text: newtext
  }));
  dispatch(saveChangesHandler({ id: ID }));
};

...

<button
  type="submit"
  onClick={() => {
    updateNodeHandler(elements);
  }}
>
  Save Changes
</button>
```